# Renaming Heroku App for Custom Domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm about to rename my Heroku app from the default one that it started with - just some jibberish, really - to something that's a little more sensical. I'm also about to wire it up with a custom domain. Is changing the app name going to cause any problems? I've read the docs and it seems like it'll be okay but wanted to ask to be sure that there weren't any namespace issues, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already configured custom domain on Heroku app. And then changed the name of the application on heroku, then you will need to update the required `CNAME` and `A` record which are pointing to `earlier.herokuapp.com`

If you haven't added the custom domain yet, rename the app first, then add the domain.

Good luck

Comment: Ah, okay, but if I haven't done either, the better route is to change the app name first, then change the CNAME and A record after to the new app name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use command line also just use below command from your project folder, by below command you no need to point to new from your git. It will automatically update your git too.

```
heroku apps:rename NEWNAME --app APP
```

NEWNAME is your new name for your heroku app

APP is old name already existing one.

If you don't know exatly the old name then you can able to view list of names and their addresses by below command

```
git remote -v
```